# What's keeping me fresh?

Tags: visual, steganography

Spinning Colors!
[image]

Rotate the colors once more and you'll find out what is keeping me fresh!

Hint 1

> There are 2+2+2=6 lines in total!

Comment: Really? Three hints right off the bat?

Comment: @Deusovi My bad. I thought I read somewhere not to add too many hints after it is already posted so I wasn't sure how many to put :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines are

> flag semaphore. Ordering them in standard red-green-blue order spells TWO. Taking "RGB" (red-green-blue) and rot-2ing them backwards gives **PEZ**, an Austrian peppermint brand.

Comment: Rot 2 the colors and you're there :)

Comment: I never knew it was originally (and still considered primarily) a mint!

Answer (score 0):

RGB (red, green, and blue) refers to a system for representing the colors to be used on a computer display.

But here this keeps you Fresh:

> "Music" because `ROT-2: tid` rot 2 of the RGB colors http://theblob.org/rot.cgi?text=rgb&rotnums=1  (RGB - TID), TID is a Bongo Flava musician from Tanzania